# Многопоточная клиент серверная система

Tags: java

При создании нескольких клиентов получаю по одному ответу от сервера для каждого клиента и на етом программа виснет. Подскажите что не так. Заранее спасибо

VServerThreads

```
public class VServerThreads {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2222);
                System.out.println("Initialized");
//            waiting for a client
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " connected");
//                creating a new thread for a new client
                    VServer vServer = new VServer(socket);
                    new Thread(vServer).start();
                }
            }finally {
                if(!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                    serverSocket.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

VServer

```
class VServer extends Thread {

    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    private static int userNumIncrement = 1;
    private int userNum = 0;
    private static DataInputStream in = null;
    private static DataOutputStream out = null;

    public VServer(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = socket;
        in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        userNum = userNumIncrement;
        userNumIncrement++;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                String line;
                while (true) {
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.print("\nReceive from user " + userNum + ": " + line);

                    if (line.startsWith("/quit")) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print("\nI am sending it back for user num " + userNum + ": " + line);
                    out.writeUTF(line);
                    out.flush();
                }

                out.writeUTF("*** Bye " + " ***");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                clientSocket.close();


        }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            this.interrupt();
        }
    }


}
```

VClient

```
public class VClient {
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static DataInputStream in = null;
    private static DataOutputStream out = null;
    private static Scanner keyboard = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String address = "127.0.0.1";
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 2222);
            try {
                keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                String line;
                while(true) {
                    line = keyboard.nextLine();
                    out.writeUTF(line);
                    out.flush();
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Waiting for the answer from the server");
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if (line.contains("*** Bye"))
                        break;

                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас поля объекта `VServer`, обслуживающего клиентские подключения, отмечены, как `static`, т.е. они общие для всех этих объектов, и когда подключается второй клиент, и создается второй объект `VServer`, данные для первого затираются.

По мелочи:

- Заворачивать `vServer` в новый `Thread` не надо, он у вас сам является наследником `Thread` (а лучше уберите наследование, реализуйте `Runnable` и используйте [пул процессов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)).
- `userNumIncrement` лучше сделать объектом `AtomicInteger`, и в конструкторе использовать `userNum = userNumIncrement.incrementAndGet()`. В вашем коде это не критично, т.к. экземпляры `VServer` создаются только в одном процессе, но вообще инкремент - не атомарная операция, и несколько процессов могут присвоить разным `vServer` одинаковые значения `userNum`.
- Для работы с потоками ввода/вывода в Java 7 и выше желательно применять конструкцию [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). `VServer.run()` можно переписать следующим образом:

  ```
  @Override
  public void run() {
      try ( 
              // для всех объектов, реализующих AutoClosable, объявленных в этом блоке
              //   будет вызван метод close(), после выхода из блока.
              Socket socket = this.clientSocket;
              DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream() );
              DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
          ) {
          while ( !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
              String line = in.readUTF();
              System.out.print("\nReceive from user " + userNum + ": " + line);

              if (line.startsWith("/quit")) {
                  break;
              }
              System.out.print("\nI am sending it back for user num " + userNum + ": " + line);
              out.writeUTF(line);
              out.flush();

          }
          out.writeUTF("*** Bye " + " ***");
      } catch ( IOException ex ) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  Поля потоков можно убрать, а в `disconnect()` вызывать `clientSocket.close()`

Comment: Большое спасибо. Все работает даже лучше чем я хотел)